# How to use JMeter for parallel executions running using postman?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, api-testing, postman, parallel-execution

**How to use JMeter for parallel executions running using postman. I want to execute close to 4000 to 5000 requests id`s at the same time and see the results.**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use JMeter to execute multiple instances of Postman tests in parallel - take a look at [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)

However I can think of a couple of possible limitations:

1. Postman is a browser plugin so it's kind of resource intensive, it will need a CPU core and a couple of gigabytes of RAM per instance so your tests will need massive infrastructure and you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
2. You won't be able to get [metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) like response time, status code, connect time, latency, work with responses and so on

So I would rather recommend converting your Postman tests into "pure" JMeter, it can be done by replaying Postman request (or collection) via JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

1. Start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
2. [Import JMeter's certificate into Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)

   [image]
3. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as a proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/proxy/)

   [image]
4. Run your request or collection in Postman
5. JMeter will capture the requests and generate relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers

In that case you won't have to launch an external application and from resources footprint perspective you will be able to generate much more load from a single machine.

Comment: can you share if you have any video links for the same for execution @dmitri-t